# Android - make GridView smaller to fit vertically without scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, imageview

I have a `Gridview` which is on about the half of the screen. It is filled with `ImageViews` which are quadratic. The problem is that the `GridView` fills the complete width and so makes it scroll vertically.

I want to reduce the width of the GridView so much that it fits vertically without scrolling. I neither want the images to get deformed nor to change the column size.

I already tried different `android:stretchMode`'s but with others than `columnWidth`it didn't showed the gridView at all.

Simply adding padding or margin is not what I want because it should fit on all screen sizes.

Here is my layout file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewPlayer2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"        
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Chronometer"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:rotation="180" />

         <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

     </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewPlayer1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"        
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >

        </GridView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a pretty good workaraound which does exactly what I want. It's pretty simple:

since my `GridView` is quadratic, I managed to get the height of the `LinearLayout` and set the width of the `GridView` with that value. (I did not directly set the width on the `GridView` but on another LinearLayout I added to solve some import problems).

So here is my xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_help_p2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewPlayer2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"        
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
                android:rotation="180" >

            </GridView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="Chronometer"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:rotation="180" />

         <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/timer_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="right" />

     </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/layout_grid_p1">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_help_p1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridViewPlayer1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"        
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="3dp" >

            </GridView>

         </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's how I managed the described process:

```js
final LinearLayout mLayoutP1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_grid_p1);
final LinearLayout mLayoutHelpP1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_help_p1);
final LinearLayout mLayoutHelpP2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_help_p2);
  
mLayoutP1.post(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
      layoutHeightP1 = mLayoutP1.getHeight();
   mLayoutHelpP1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layoutHeightP1, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   mLayoutHelpP2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(layoutHeightP1, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 }
   
});
```

So the result is: http://abload.de/img/4cu7w.jpg

This workaround only works because my `GridView`is quadratic. If someone found a way to automatically reduce the width of a `GridView`/`ListView` that it fits vertically on the screen without scrolling, feel free to share it here!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what exactly you are looking for. But you can set the width of the grid view and column width of the grid view dynamically.

Comment: I made a Screenshot which shows the problem.  The last row is cut off and I have to scroll to make it completely visible. What I want is to reduce the width of the whole Gridview that it fits vertically. http://www.abload.de/img/viuwl.jpg (Unfortunately I cannot upload images directly here)